# call function inside <script type="module"> from <script type="text/javascript>

Tags: javascript

Is there any way that use a function declared inside `<script type="module">` from `<script type="text/javascript>`?

For example,

```
<script type="module">
   function do_something(){ ... };
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
   do_something();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is bad practice**

You can explicitly make a variable a global, but modules appear to be loaded asynchronously so you need to wait until the module has been evaluated.

I'm using DOMContentLoaded here, but I don't know if that is reliable.

```html
<script type="module">
  function do_something() { console.log("Something"); } window.do_something = do_something;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    do_something();
  })
</script>
```

---

Instead of doing that, you should design your JS to not need globals in the first place.

Use a module as the entry point into your program, not a non-module.

Comment: @Wooni You really missed the point that both answers wanted to make, that is to avoid use of globals..sigh

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no (unless you wish to pollute the global namespace).

[MDN Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) on modules states this clearly.

> Last but not least, let's make this clear — module features are imported into the scope of a single script — they aren't available in the global scope. Therefore, you will only be able to access imported features in the script they are imported into, and you won't be able to access them from the JavaScript console, for example. You'll still get syntax errors shown in the DevTools, but you'll not be able to use some of the debugging techniques you might have expected to use.